# git rebasing from local branch off remote branch

Tags: git, github

I have a local branch `test`, and I want to rebase off of the remote branch `test`, how would I do this? I have tried `git rebase origin test`, but the changes someone pushed a short while ago aren't being rebased into my local?

Answer (score 16):

You have to first fetch data from the server (this won't affect your branch, but will update the branch `origin/test` with the remote changes).

```
git fetch
```

Then you can do your rebase

```
git rebase origin/test
```

You can now push your branch `test`

```
git push origin test
```